# Azure API Extract <send-request> policy's response status code

Tags: azure, response, azure-api-management, azure-policy, inbound

I'm making request using  policy.. I need to check the status code of that request

I tried using

```xml
<choose>
  <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["LogFailedEvent"]).StatusCode != 200)">
  </when>
</choose>
```

even

```xml
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode != 200)">
  </when>
</choose>
```

but it throws error like `key not present in dictionary`
anyone have idea/solution?

Answer (score 0):

If ignore-error attribute is set to "true" in your send-request policy, APIM will continue without setting response variable to anything. Trace your call using Test console in Azure portal to see where and why it breaks.